# After second user login first user data upadated in home page with second user

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new with NodeJS and Express, and I got stuck with some probably trivial issue that I can't solve on my own. I've been trying to fix this code myself, but all my efforts were pointless.

Basically I'm looking to make simple web app which supports user logins and shows data related for logged-in user (user profile). And that's what I managed to do on my own. Sort of. After starting up application, "user1" logs-in and data gets displayed for said user, however after logging in as a different user (user2) in other browser, both user sessions show same database results (results got from second user - "user2").I am using mysql database

Please ........... I'd be really grateful if you could give me the answer.

Here is my code for home when user login

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  var query = "select f.id,f.floor_name,r.id,r.room_name,d.id,d.device_name,d.channel from floors f left outer join rooms r on f.id=r.floor_id left outer join devices d on d.room_id=r.id where f.user_id="+session._id;


        connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var data = JSON.stringify(rows);

    res.render('home',{ 
      floordata:data);
      });
```

and here is my user login code....

```
connection.getConnection(function (err) { if (!err) { var query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name='" + req.body.name + "' and password = '" + req.body.password + "'"; connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) { if (err) throw err; var data = JSON.stringify(rows); session._id=rows[0].id; console.log("login_user_id--"+session._id); res.redirect('/home');
```

Comment: Can you provide more detailed code from your project? Currently it is not possible to say which line of code causes the problem.

Comment: I provide my updated code

Comment: Based on your code `session` is a global object  so it is the same for all requests. where do you create and set `session`?

Comment: As I see your session._id variable always has the last value. I think you have to focus it. Can you provide the code block which you mutate session variable?